# Codeigniter Pagination lib don't work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my Code :

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "Reports/payment";
$config["total_rows"] = 40/;
$config["per_page"] = 20;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data['main_content'] = $this->module . '/' . $page;
$this->load->view('admin/page', $data);
```

Here is the Error String:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function initialize() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs....

Things i have tried so far:
1.i autoload the the pagination lib **[no-luck]**,
2.i create a library in the library and load through that **[no-luck]**,
4.i load the lib in the same constructor **[no-luck]**,
5.i tried with Uppercase `Pagination` **[no-luck]**,
i don't know where is the problem .
i search alot but no luck.
please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Did you try with lowercase? `$this->load->library('pagination');` and `$this->pagination->initialize($config);`

Comment: yes i tried but no luck

Comment: Read my question again ,especially the 5th point of "things i have tried so far" portion .

Comment: I am not sure but try to remove comment in this line `$config["total_rows"] = 40;`

Comment: comments mean code to be skip .it don't effect code

Comment: check `application/config/pagination.php` are present in your config or not

Comment: Every library can be loaded with upper and lower case ,
it don't matter if you still don't believe try loading any library .
for you i edit my question

Comment: @saty there is no file name `pagination` in the `application/config`

Comment: Read this [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#setting-preferences-in-a-config-file). Try to create this file and check

Comment: to use pagination library you must use lowercase every where. Tested

Comment: set  $this->pagination->base_url = base_url() . "Reports/payment";
and print $this->pagination see base_url value is set ?

Comment: You've cut an important part of the error message ... Where are you calling this code from? Also, check your logfiles ... if the library load fails, there should be an error logged.

Answer (score -2):

Try to load pagination library to custom  object like:

```
$CI = get_instance();

$CI->load->library('pagination');
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "Reports/payment";
$config["total_rows"] = 40;
$config["per_page"] = 20;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$CI->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data["links"] = $CI->pagination->create_links();
$data['main_content'] = $this->module . '/' . $page;
$this->load->view('admin/page', $data);
```